# Connected to Postgresql error

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, tcp

I am trying to connect to Postgres and this is the error message that I get:

```
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
[main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I have verified that username/password is fine in my hibernate.conf

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">*******</property>
```

This is my pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
# host   postgres,replication    localhost   127.0.0.1/32    md5
# host   postgres,replication    localhost   ::1/128     md5
host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5
```

I am working on Windows (Not UNIX). So please suggest how I can fix this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: hi
Postgres by default runs on port 5432 . Check whether your postgres process is running or not and if yes then on which port.

Comment: The postgres is running on 5432. I did check that but still the same issue. Please check my pg_hba.conf if i need to make any changes yet.

Comment: NFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres..As per your log you are trying to make a connection on 5433 and your postgres is running on 5432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where is port no in the connection url .
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:`portno`/postgres

so final url should be according to db server port as on my pc

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```